# make a custom font bold

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a custom font (poiret) that doesn't have bold type. I would like to use it in my application as bold. In android `Typeface.BOLD` makes so-called virtual bold typeface. Is there any way to make it bold in xcode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make Custom font **BOLD**. Instead, You have to download its `bold-version`and use that in your *View*. Only system fonts can be styled to **BOLD**

Comment: Though I never tried, I'm pretty sure this can be done with CoreText. Pretty good question actually.

Comment: Not Sure! Haven't used it before.